# Thread safe map which preserves the insertion order

Tags: scala, collections, thread-safety

In my Scala application I need to use several Maps and Lists which gets updated very often. Are there any thread safe collections in Scala which maintain the insertion order?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a trait in the `scala.collection.concurrent` package: [concurrent.Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.Map) it's just a trait, so just mixin this trait into your Map and it would become thread-safe.

If you need a good concurrent map, try google's [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/) (last release 2015) and convert it to Scala Map using [Scala/Java converter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html), that will give more performance that mixin `SynchronizedMap`. For example my favourite [Spray](https://github.com/spray/spray) toolkit, [use](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-caching/src/main/scala/spray/caching/LruCache.scala#L107) it as a core structure for implmenting it's caching module. As you can [see](http://spray.io/blog/2013-05-24-benchmarking-spray/), spray is the fastest Scala web toolkit

Comment: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,Any] -> this is the map that am using. How do I make it thread safe acc to you?

Comment: I similarly tried `new scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Long] with scala.collection.concurrent.Map[String, Long]` which fails to compile: `object creation impossible, since:
[error] it has 8 unimplemented members.` (error message truncated to fit comment). Switching to `LinkedHashMap` yields only 4 unimplemented members... I think it relates to the use of `Long` yet not sure what to make out of this... feels slightly awkward adding support for Long on my own or degressing from `Long` to `Any` for this. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about lists then?