# Scala - Mutable thread safe collections

Tags: multithreading, scala, collections, dictionary, thread-safety

I need a mutable thread safe Map and a mutable thread safe List in Scala. I know that the immutable collections are thread safe by default. But, I need to update my collections very often because of which I couldn't use immutable. Also I need my threadsafe mutable Map to maintain the insertion order.

Right now am using the map below

```
val map = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,Any]()
```

This map maintains the insertion order and is mutable. How do I make it thread safe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread safe map which preserves the insertion order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540467/thread-safe-map-which-preserves-the-insertion-order)

Comment: @AlexIv not a duplicate in complete sense -- rahul asks about List too

Comment: @om-nom-nom anyway it could be modified, but create a new question is excess

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As was mentioned by [AlexIv in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17540535/1180426), there's a trait you can mix in if you want thread safety. There's another way though:

```
    val synchronizedMap = new scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, Any]() with scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedMap[String, Any]
```

That should give you the [map with synchronization on each access](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedMap.html). Easy, but might not meet the performance requirements. If so, it would be probably easier to create a custom class extending the `LinkedHashMap`, mixing in the [`concurrent.Map` trait (as was suggested)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.Map) and provide the implementation of relevant methods, i.e: `putIfAbsent`, `remove` `replace` (2 overloads).

Comment: If you can stand a bit more work, use the `synchronized` method on the mutable collection directly where you need thread safety. It'll save you the performance hit that this mixin brings. E.g. `someMap.synchronized { someMap += ("someKey", "anyValue") }`

Comment: For anyone new viewing this, the SynchronizedMap trait has been deprecated as not safe enough. Recommends using Java thread safe collections.

Comment: It's a compiler warning when you build after mixing in this trait - not sure about a link

Comment: @Gepp: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedMap.html: "(Since version 2.11.0) Synchronization via traits is deprecated as it is inherently unreliable. Consider `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` as an alternative."

Comment: TrieMap is mutable, thread-safe, lock-free, and is not deprecated

Comment: > @deprecated("Synchronization via traits is deprecated as it is inherently unreliable. Consider java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap as an alternative.", "2.11.0")
trait SynchronizedMap[A, B] extends Map[A, B] {
it's deprecated already.

Answer (score 46):

Fast hint for those coming to this in 2018 or later:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

val m: ConcurrentHashMap[String,MyClass] = new ConcurrentHashMap
```

Comment: Is it still valid in 2021?

Comment: Yes, it is valid. The "synchronized" collections in Scala are deprecated since Scala 2.11.0. It is recommended to use `java.util.concurrent.` package.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the comment for a `Map` you can use

```
import scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap
```

Is not deprecated and is mutable and thread-safe.

It should drop in for your `scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap` as they share the same interface of `scala.collection.mutable.MapLike` and `scala.collection.mutable.Map`

Sadly I don't know about the `List`